# removeEventListener not working in IE10, works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, mutation-observers, mutation-events

I am trying to create a mini library using `MutationObserver` to detect changes in DOM but also to fallback to basic Mutation Events in older browsers. So far so good, it works properly in Chrome and Firefox and I tested the fallback in these browsers too - everything worked but when I tested it IE 10 it behaves differently (how unexpected...)

In this library you can simply call:

```
domWatch(someDOMNode, callback)
```

callback gets one parameter - an observer with disconnect and observe methods so you can stop watching the node while you do some changes to it and then start watching again.

```
domWatch(document.querySelector('div'), function (obs) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        obs.disconnect();
        $(obs.node).append('a');
        obs.observe();
    }, 1200);
});
```

In the fallback I use mutation events and add/remove event listeners. I think the problem is that in IE the event is not really removed is, it gets stuck in infinite loop (my code is in `setTimeout` so it will not crash your browser). For some reason it probably thinks that `this.realCallback` are different functions?

```
FallbackObserver.prototype.observe = function () {
    this.node.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", this.realCallback, true);
}

FallbackObserver.prototype.disconnect = function () {
    this.node.removeEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", this.realCallback, true);
}
```

I created a mini fiddle only with the problematic code, try to run it in Chrome and then in IE10: http://jsfiddle.net/Hb45w/2/

(Full library Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x6W3p/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it:

All browsers were correctly removing and adding events - the problem was something else.

The actual problem with IE is probably some aspect of rendering engine - I disconnected the event handler, did the change and started observing again:

```
    obs.disconnect();
    $(obs.node).append('a');
    obs.observe();
```

The problem was that the event was obviously attached back **before** IE finished the rendering (probably some asynchronous execution).

Changing

```
FallbackObserver.prototype.observe = function () {
    this.node.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", this.realCallback, true);
}
```

to

```
FallbackObserver.prototype.observe = function () {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
       that.node.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", that.realCallback, true);
    }, 0);
}
```

did the trick. But I am not sure whether it will work if some more complex DOM changes will be performed.